# How to fix this Error expression must have a class type and C228?

Tags: c++

I'm new in C++. I'm trying to write sample code from my Java Book to practice C++.

Here the source code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void tampilkanMatriks(int matriks[3][2]);
void tampilkanMatriks(int matriks[3][2])
{
    int jumBaris = matriks.length;
    int jumKolom = matriks[0].length;

    for (int i = 0; i < jumBaris; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < jumKolom; j++)
            printf("%4d", matriks[i][j]);

        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int mat[3][2];

    mat[0][0] = 70;
    mat[0][1] = 80;

    mat[1][0] = 64;
    mat[1][1] = 55;

    mat[2][0] = 76;
    mat[2][1] = 72;

    tampilkanMatriks(mat);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Error : expression must have a class type in line 7, expression must have a class type in line 8, C2228 error in line 7 and 8.

Comment: How about learning C++ with a C++ book? C-style arrays are not class types.

Comment: I learn C++ with a C++ book too. I just practice with my Java Book. Can you fix my syntax to fix the error? :D

Comment: `int jumBaris = 2, jumKolom = 3;`.

Comment: @MuhammadFaqih _I just practice with my Java Book_ Hint: C++ and Java are different languages, and what works in one, won't necessarily work in another.

Comment: Thank You :). I think C++ and Java are same, my opinion tolally. Because I have read some code from Java and try to write it in C++ and that's work.

Comment: @MuhammadFaqih Do you seriously think, that Java, is the same as C++? Ignorance is a bliss, I guess.

Comment: Yes, I do hehehe. But now I don't think like that again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Arrays` are not class objects. `matriks.length` is invalid. The `.` operator is used for `class` and `struct`. Since you have `hard typed` the dimensions of the array you can always use them to iterate through the array. Although this is not a good solution. In general, when you are dealing with arrays its best to pass an extra argument which corresponds to the size of the array. If you need to use a `class` you have`std::vector`.

Comment: "Since you have hard typed the dimensions of the array" But the function parameters are pointer to length-2 array, so only one dimension is known (in the function.)

Comment: @juanchopanza sorry for the confusion, the array length is already known at compile time [3][2] so he can you use a `for loop` to iterate through these values. He can always write `for( int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)`. Unfortunately, this is a very bad approach and that's why I mentioned that it is better to pass a `size` argument or use an `std::vector`.

Comment: Thank you for the solution :D

Comment: @juanchopanza btw the compiler sees an array of length `2` but he already knows the dimensions. But again this is bad but I believe it was worth mentioning it so he can avoid it in the feature.

Comment: @KostasRim "If you need to use a class you have std::vector." Am I mistaken or are you suggesting a beginner to store his matrix as a `std:vector<std::vector<int>>` if he needs a class?

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi I am not suggesting anything. He mentioned that he comes from `java` so I am guessing that his already familiar with classes. If that's the case he can do some digging and learn about `vectors`. He did try to treat an `array` as a `class`. Another approach is to use a `std::vector<int>` and treat it as a `2d` array.  Again because I can't be sure, I chose to write 3 different approaches, 2 of them involve arrays and 1 a container.

Answer (score 0):

No, sorry. Unlike Java, you don't get to ask for the length of an array like this:

```
int jumBaris = matriks.length;
int jumKolom = matriks[0].length;
```

You have to know your lengths in advance.
Google for "arrays in C" - heaps of places.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you. I think C++ as same as Java. My opinion is totaly wrong.